# Is there any modern video connector you can use royalties free?

Tags: connector, video

I would like to make several hundreds of a device with video out. It seems every video connector involves huge fees for licensing - is there anyway around this?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't DP royalty-free?

Comment: VGA is as well, but that might be a little less modern than you want.

Comment: @Hearth free as in "just buy the connectors" and use them free?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, as long as you're not using HDCP (which you shouldn't be anyway (I have strong feelings about the ethicality of DRM, namely that it isn't)) you can use it free of charge, just buy the physical connectors.

Comment: I thought you had to license the codecs

Comment: There are no codecs here. It is uncompressed digital video pixels sent over wire.

Comment: More information about resolution, expected frequencies etc. would help. You could just use a set of cinch plugs. Or you can use (HD)/SDI where you can have SMA or BNC plugs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For devices and endpoints the contemporary digital interconnects have an ensnarement with HDCP. This includes both HDMI and DisplayPort, which can support driving HDMI with an ‘active cable’ adapter.

Besides HDCP, HDMI has a ‘Logo License’ that costs serious money. DP doesn’t, though MPEG LA wants to charge a (disputed) $0.20 per unit royalty fee.

DVI doesn’t have an HDCP requirement, it’s optional, and it has no fees. This might be a reasonable choice that’s still supported in the marketplace, and it’s supported as a legacy mode in HDMI with a passive adapter.  (Yes I’m aware of TMDS patents. As a practical matter those are rolled up in the source/sink device, not the connector itself.)

An HDMI source however can choose not to send DRM-enforced content over DVI, or it can down-res it to 480p. This applies to any device that it can’t identify as HDCP compliant, including DisplayPort that isn’t HDCP enabled.

Where would this come up? Pretty much any playback of copyrighted material, including streaming and packaged media.

DRM sucks. And I say that as someone whose signature is on an HDCP license.

Comment: Really? I always thought DP was completly free from this licencing stuff.

Comment: It depends on the material you want to send. If it has DRM enforcement then you need HDCP. DVI, being a legacy format, has no explicit restriction, though a source could refuse to send a DRM-protected source, or down-res it to 480p.

Comment: But yes, there’s no license required for DP. There is a small royalty of $0.20/unit payable to MPEG LA.

Comment: The MPEG LA claim on DP is under dispute by the way.

Comment: @hacktastical The "content" to be transmitted is video games from the source device. There is no option for any other content. Source resolution is also low, 640 x 480. Assuming I don't use any logos and such - DP is the only option for digital video it seems?

Comment: DP could work then, as could DVI.  Also consider MHL, which repurposes micro USB for one digital lane of video.

Comment: One more thing: USB type C has video-out alternate modes for DP, HDMI and MHL. More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_devices_with_video_output_over_USB-C

Comment: @user733606 given the low source resolution, you could also just use old-fashioned VGA.

Answer (score -2):

HDMI is out of question then, you need to pay member fees to legally manufacture devices with HDMI interface. Even worse if you need HDCP protection, but you don't need HDCP if your device is a camera or similar which is not meant to play NetFlix or Blu-Ray discs. That said, you can buy HDMI and DVI encoder chips, and you can use DVI protocol with DVI connectors. DVI connector can be used for analog video as well. Displayport should be doable as well.